# react-youtube TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'playVideo')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'playVideo')

Call Stack
eval
node_modules/react-youtube/node_modules/youtube-player/dist/index.js (65:0)
new Promise

exports.default
node_modules/react-youtube/node_modules/youtube-player/dist/index.js (64:0)
createPlayer
node_modules/react-youtube/dist/YouTube.esm.js (170:41)

https://upload.cc/i1/2023/02/26/daWAmu.png

This error may occur when I click pagination to get the video or just load the page,I show three videos on page, and change the page when want to get more. Sorry for the English not my native language.

React 18.2.0
Next 13.1.6
react-youtube 10.1.0

```
const Playlist = ({ playlistId }) => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 640 });
  const isPad = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 1180 });
  const videosPerPage = isMobile ? 1 : isPad ? 2 : 3;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=${playlistId}&key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ytAPI}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setVideos(data.items);
        console.log('data: ', data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [playlistId]);

  const handlePageClick = ({ selected }) => {
    setCurrentPage(selected);
  };

  const currentVideos = useMemo(() => {
    const offset = currentPage * videosPerPage;
    return videos.slice(offset, offset + videosPerPage);
  }, [currentPage, videos, videosPerPage]);

  const getOpts = useCallback(() => {
    return {
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
      },
    };
  }, []);

  const opts = getOpts();

  return (
    <>
      <div className='flex container justify-center my-10'>
        {currentVideos.map((video) => (
          <div
            key={video.id}
            className='w-full'
          >
            <YouTubePlayer
              className='video-container'
              videoId={video.snippet.resourceId.videoId}
              opts={opts}
            />
            <h2 className='text-center m-4'>{video.snippet.title}</h2>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <ReactPaginate
        className='item flex w-full justify-center mb-8'
        previousLabel={'« prev'}
        nextLabel={'next »'}
        breakLabel={'...'}
        marginPagesDisplayed={0}
        activeClassName={'active'}
        breakClassName={'disabled'}
        containerClassName={'pagination'}
        pageCount={Math.ceil(videos.length / videosPerPage)}
        onPageChange={handlePageClick}
        forcePage={currentPage}
        pageRangeDisplayed={3}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Playlist;
```

I tried to replace react-youtube with react-player but got the same error message so I think it might not be caused by npm package

Comment: Can you share example `videos` data?

Comment: Sorry I can't share the key, videos data from youtube api

Comment: can you share the github repo or create a reproducible repo, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'playVideo')" seems to suggest that there's an issue with the video player initialization.

It looks like the YouTubePlayer component is being used before it is properly initialized, or it is trying to access the 'playVideo' property when the video player is null. Here are a few suggestions to help you fix this issue:

Ensure that the videoId is not null or undefined before rendering the YouTubePlayer component. You can add a conditional check like this:

```
{video.snippet.resourceId.videoId && (
  <YouTubePlayer
    className='video-container'
    videoId={video.snippet.resourceId.videoId}
    opts={opts}
  />
)}
```

Make sure that the video player library is properly loaded before using it. You can try wrapping the YouTubePlayer component with the ReactPlayer component from the react-player package. This will load the YouTube iframe API before initializing the player. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/youtube';

// ...

{video.snippet.resourceId.videoId && (
  <ReactPlayer
    className='video-container'
    url={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.snippet.resourceId.videoId}`}
    config={{
      youtube: {
        playerVars: {
          autoplay: 0,
        },
      },
    }}
  />
)}
```

Make sure you have the react-player package installed. You can install it using npm or yarn:

```
npm install react-player
```

or

```
yarn add react-player
```

These changes should help resolve the error you're experiencing. If the issue persists, please provide additional information or a more detailed error message, so we can further diagnose the problem.

Comment: I changed to react-player and it's work. No error now, thanks!
https://www.easy4music.com/%E4%BD%9C%E5%93%81%E9%9B%86

Comment: My pleasure, but my bounty is dead :/

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to wait for the fetch request to the API. You can restructure your code like this:

```js
const Playlist = ({ playlistId }) => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=${playlistId}&key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ytAPI}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setVideos(data.items);
        setIsLoading(false); // set isLoading to false after data is fetched
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setIsLoading(false); // also set isLoading to false on error
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [playlistId]);

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className='flex container justify-center my-10'>
          {currentVideos.map((video) => (
            <div key={video.id} className='w-full'>
              <YouTubePlayer
                className='video-container'
                videoId={video.snippet.resourceId.videoId}
                opts={opts}
              />
              <h2 className='text-center m-4'>{video.snippet.title}</h2>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
      {/* ... */}
    </>
  );
};
```

Now it shows `Loading...` until you get a response from the API.